# show programmatic storyboard view changes

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS dev, and coming from a Windows background, I was able to see any programmatic changes made to ui elements reflected on the designer. If I wanted to, say, round the corners of a button (programmatically is the only way  have found), but see the changes reflected on the storyboard, is this possible?

Comment: Check this: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards are very useful for building simple framework for apps, however it falls somewhat short when displaying custom interfaces.

The advantage of using storyboards is to have everything one one clear, concise page, with view controllers and transitions, rather than using XIBs. It eliminates a good amount of code that is needed in order for your app to run (for certain transitions between views, for example,) and also changes the required boilerplate code that is needed for certain classes like

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

I believe a lot of advanced iOS applications have custom views or some special ways of presenting content, however storyboards are very often used as well.

edit: it seems that a new feature is in Xcode 6 that I didn't know about! Found a very nice tutorial on how to show some of the features you would like.

https://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/

(credit to the commenter on your post for linking to another IBInspectable tutorial)

Comment: So what you're saying is there is no "Designer" in Xcode that does what I need?

Comment: Check my edit-- I'm not familiar with a windows "designer" but the tutorial I linked might be of good use to you!

Comment: Your edit was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!